# PhpMyAdmin SQL query to return multiple records on inner joined tables with count

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables in a database, 'invoices' and 'customers'. I am trying to create a query which displays a list of customers that have placed 
two or more orders. The following statements work if I only look at a single customer (in this case customer with id 'C120').

```
SELECT `invoices`.date,`customers`.name FROM `invoices` 
INNER JOIN `customers` 
ON `invoices`.cust_id=`customers`.cust_id 
WHERE `invoices`.cust_id = 'C120'
HAVING COUNT(`invoices`.date) >=2;
```

However I would like a view of all customers meeting the search criteria.

I have tried using LIKE in the following form:

```
WHERE (`customers`.`cust_id` LIKE 'C%')
```

(all customer ids are four characters beginning with 'C') but all this does is return the first customer in 'customers' which dosen't even satisfy the >= 2 condition.Also tried

```
WHERE `invoices`.cust_id = 'C*'
```

which returns an empty set.

I have run out of ideas and would appreciate some help, thanks.

The customer table is as follows:

```
cust_id     name
C100    Bloggs
C110    Pekkonen
C120    Finklefluffle
```

The invoice table is:

```
date    cust_id     amount
2017-10-09  C100    27.78
2017-11-28  C110    409.66
2017-10-17  C110    2729.3
2017-10-09  C120    2.66
2017-11-06  C110    300
2017-11-21  C120    59.65
```

What I want the reult to be is:

```
C110 Pekkonen
C120 Finklefluffle
```

or even better

```
C110 Pekkonen 3
C120 Finklefluffle 2
```

What I get with

```
WHERE (`customers`.`cust_id` LIKE 'C%')
```

is completely wrong:

```
C100    Bloggs
```

and what I get with

```
WHERE `invoices`.cust_id = 'C*'
```

is 'empty data set' .. also incorrect.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Your logic all looks correct to me.  Plesse edit your question and show sample data, along with the output you get and what the output should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
    SELECT `customers`.cust_id , `customers`.name, count(*) FROM `invoices` 
    INNER JOIN `customers` 
    ON `invoices`.cust_id=`customers`.cust_id 
    GROUP BY `customers`.cust_id , `customers`.name
    HAVING COUNT(`invoices`.date) >=2;
```